# PHP pagination SQL Syntax error when page= -1

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

When I check this url for page pagination, pagination worked and show page result in page and page=+1:

```
mydomain/search.php?page=1

mydomain/search.php?page=2
```

But when I check with this url:

```
mydomain/search.php?page=-1

mydomain/search.php?page=-2
```

I see this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-20, 10' at line 1
```

I print result using this pagination code:

```
// If number of results is bigger than the maximum number
  // of search results set in config we start the pagination
  if ( $results > $conf['search_results'] )

   {

    // Calculate the first number of page to show
    // This makes the list of pages numbers smaller
    if ((($page*$conf['search_results'])-($conf['search_results']*5)) >= 0) 
     $first=($page*$conf['search_results'])-($conf['search_results']*5);
    else 
     $first=0;

    // Calculate the last element of the pagination list
    if ((($page*$conf['search_results'])+($conf['search_results']*6)) <= $results) 
     $last =($page*$conf['search_results'])+($conf['search_results']*6);
    else 
     $last = $results;

    @    $i=$first/$conf['search_results'];

    // Previous link
    if ($page > 0)
     {
      $pagenum = $page - 1;
      echo ' <a style="float:left;" href="' . URL . '/search.php?page=' . $pagenum . '&amp;' . $session->fetch('listingsearchvariablespage') . '">PRE</a> | ';
     }

    // Middle pagination
    for ( $step = $first; $step < $last; $step=$step+$conf['search_results'] )

     {

      if ( $i == $page )

       {

    $pagenum = $i+1;
    echo ' <span class="warning">' . $pagenum . '</span> | ';
    $i++;

       }

      else

       {

    $pagenum = $i+1;
    echo ' <a href="' . URL . '/search.php?page=' . $i . '&amp;' . $session->fetch('listingsearchvariablespage') . '">' . $pagenum . '</a> | ';
    $i++;

       }

     }

    // Next link
    if ($page - (($results / $conf['search_results']) - 1) < 0)
     {
      $pagenum = $page+1;
      echo ' <a style="float:right;" href="' . URL . '/search.php?page=' . $pagenum . '&amp;' . $session->fetch('listingsearchvariablespage') . '">NEXT</a>';      
     }

   }
```

Now, how do can I fix this error for Negative number and prevent any attack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend something simple like:

```
if($page < 1)
    $page = 1;
```

Comment: agree. I would also add $page = (int)$_GET['page']; to prevent anything other than integer to be passed in the url

Comment: @andrew, yeah - I sort of assumed he'd done that but I guess you never know.

Answer (score 0):

`LIMIT -20,10` is invalid syntax - you can't have a negative offset. You should clamp the value to the valid range of pages.

Comment: I know! i need to prevent this for any attacks. i think block Negative number.